# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} - \sqrt{1 + \sin x}}{x^3}$

Tags: limits, derivatives

What I attempted thus far:

Multiplying by conjugate

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} - \sqrt{1 + \sin x}}{x^3} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x}}{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x}} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3 \cdot (\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x})}$$

factor out $\sin x$ in the numerator

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x \cdot (\sec x - 1)}{x^3 \cdot (\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x})}$$

simplify using $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1 $

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sec x - 1}{x^2 \cdot (\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x})}$$

From here I don't see any useful direction to go in, if I even went in an useful direction in the first place, I don't know.

---

I suspect that this could be evaluated using the definition of derivatives, if so, or not, any suggestions?

Comment: one easy step is $\sqrt{1+\tan x} + \sqrt{1+\sin x}\to 2$.

Comment: Use $\sec x-1=(1-\cos x)/\cos x=2(\sin^2x/2)/\cos x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I forget about the half-angle formulas. Thanks for reminding me. I solved it using your suggestion, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You are doing well. Now multiply top and bottom by $\sec x+1$, and note that $\sec^2 x-1=\tan^2 x$.

Comment: I've got the bad habit of not multiplying by the conjugate if I've done it once already. You've brought this to my attention in addition to assisting me solve the problem. As always, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sec x - 1}{x^2 \cdot (\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x})} &= \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan x} + \sqrt{1 + \sin x}}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sec x-1}{x^2}\\
&=\frac12 \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sec x-1}{x^2}
\end{align}$

This last limit should yield to L'Hopital's rule, or you could multiply by the conjugate of the numerator and apply a trig identity, plus the fact that $\frac{\tan x}{x}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use Taylor series, you could start with $$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^5}{15}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^7\right)$$ Now, use $$\sqrt{1+y}=1+\frac{y}{2}-\frac{y^2}{8}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ Replacing $y$ by the previous developments, you then have  $$\sqrt{1+\tan(x)}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{11 x^3}{48}-\frac{47 x^4}{384}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ $$\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{48}+\frac{x^4}{384}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ $$\sqrt{1+\tan(x)}-\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}=\frac{x^3}{4}-\frac{x^4}{8}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ and finally $$\frac{\sqrt{1+\tan(x)}-\sqrt{1+\sin(x)}}{x^3}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{x}{8}+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached when $x$ goes to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac { \sqrt{1+\tan(x)} - \sqrt{1+sin(x)}} { x^3 } = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {tan(x) - sin(x)} {x^3(\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1+sin(x)})} =  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {sin(x)(\frac {1} {cos(x)} - 1)} {x^3(\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1+sin(x)})} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1 - cos(x)} {cos(x)x^2(\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1+sin(x)})} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {x^2} {2cos(x)x^2(\sqrt{1+\tan(x)} + \sqrt{1+sin(x)})} = \frac {1} {4} $

Intermediate calculations:
$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac {2(1 - cos(x))} {x^2} = 1 $$
$$ \lim_{x\to0} cos(x) = 1 $$
$$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac {sin(x)}{x} = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a symbolic differentiation program like Matlab and have forgotten your trig and calculus formulas like I have, you should be able to recover the answer as $$\frac{\frac{d^3(\sqrt{1 + \tan x} - \sqrt{1 + \sin x})}{dx^3}}{\frac{d^3(x^3)}{dx^3}} = \frac{\frac{d^3(\sqrt{1 + \tan x} - \sqrt{1 + \sin x})}{dx^3}}{6}$$ evaluated at $x=0$.  This result is derived by applying the L'Hopital rule three times.  The denominator will reduce to $3!=6$, and the numerator can be calculated by the computer.  Even if you are trying to show your work, it never hurts to have a computer verify your answer.

Comment: I managed to get the answer by graphing the function, luckily it was a solid $\frac{1}{4}$. But I should invest some time in getting the hang of software like Matlab. Thank you, Ashwin.